# How to set a before_action only for default RESTful actions in Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes

I have a controller with the default RESTful route actions (`index` `new` `create` `show` `edit` `update` `destroy`) and also several other actions. I want to set a `before_action` that only runs on the default routes.

I know I can add `before_action :set_x, only: [:index, :new, :create, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]` to the top of the controller but is there a quicker way to do this? I'd like to do this for multiple controllers, so I cannot do `before_action :set_x, except: [:foo, :bar, :baz]` because the actions change in each controller and new actions are added all the time.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to do it on application_controller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

- define the `before_action` in the `ApplicationController`
- write `skip_before_action` in those controllers that do not need it
- define another "controller"-class, that derives from `ApplicationController`, add the `before_action` and only those controllers that need it, will inherit from that class
- create a module with only the `before_action` and include it